# Is it possible to make fullcalendar not overflow events?

Tags: json, fullcalendar

I'm trying to get `fullcalendar` to work with my `JSON` data, and so far it is going good.

I've got my `JSON` loaded and everything but on certain days their are a lot of events.

Is it possible to make it so each square in the calendar is a set height?

I've tried both `contentHeight` and `height` but neither of them seemed to help with this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, see http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/display/eventLimit/ for details on the `eventLimit` option introduced in v2.1.0 of FullCalendar.